# Laravel + AngularJs, use base path with ng-scr instead of the current one

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, laravel, laravel-5.1

I'll try to explain my issue as clear as I can. I'm trying to use angularJs in my Laravel project for the very first time.
The controller just fetches the uploaded photos from the database

```
public function index()
    {
        JavaScript::put([
            'photos' => Photo::all()
        ]);

        return view('pages.protected.photos.index');
    }
```

I'm using the PHP-Vars-To-Js package from laracast (that's the JavaScript facade you see) to pass my PHP photos object over to my javascript. But this isn't a problem, it works pretty well. Now, thanks to that package, I can get the photos object right into my angular controller simply by

```
$scope.photoList = photos;
```

So far so good. Now I want to actually display the images and to get that I did set a div

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="photo in photoList">
```

Inside the div there's

```
<img ng-src="@{{ photo.path }}">
```

The problem is: photos path is something like photo/picture.png, where photo is a folder in the public directory and the page where I'm trying to display the images (photos) is in a `route group`  with the `/admin` prefix (at the end something like www.myapp.com/admin/photos). When I try to display the image I get a 404 error cause it's looking for the photos src in `www.myapp.com/admin/photo/picture.png` instead of `www.myapp.com/photo/picture.png`.
My question is: how can I 'force' to use the base url in order to search for the right photo path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to add a method in the controller to get the baseURL.

**Angular Controller**

```
$scope.getImageSourceFromPhotoPath = function (photoPath) {
    return window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host + '/' + photoPath;
}
```

**Template**

```
<div class="row" ng-repeat="photo in photoList">
    <img ng-src="getImageSourceFromPhotoPath(photo.path)">
</div>
```

Comment: I tried out your solution but it doesn't quite work for me. I get back a 404 as well, as now it's searching in `www.myapp.com/admin/getImageSourceFromPhotoPath(photo.path)`

Comment: @MisterP ah, that means you have your angular app installed in the admin direction. In that case I would use window.location.origin instead of angular'a $location service.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to try your fix as soon as possible. I do have angular installed in the admin section cause I'm using AngularBooter and not just a standard angular app.

Comment: I updated my original answer. Try that snippet for getting the baseURL programmatically.

Comment: Thanks, with your update now it works like it's supposed to.

Comment: i need to get the image without using function